# How do I get an ipywidget to respond to changes in a global variable?

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I have

```py
@widgets.interact(
    x_max=widgets.IntSlider(min=1, max=100, step=1, value=10, continuous_update=True, description='$x_{max}$'), 
    N=widgets.IntSlider(min=5, max=25, step=1, value=10, continuous_update=True, description='$N$'))
def update_data(x_max, N):
    global data
    data = np.random.randint(0, x_max+1, N)
    print(data)
```

and

```py
@widgets.interact(
    T=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.01, max=10, step=0.05, value=1, continuous_update=False, description='$T$'),
    data.widgets)
def plot_histograms(T):
    global data
    if data is None:
        print("Please generate data using the sliders above.")
        return

    plot_data(data, T)
```

and want changes to the random `data` to trigger an plot, by updating what `plot_histogram` displays.

Is there a way to do that? The crucial thing is that

1. I don't want new (random) data to be generated each time I change `T`, but
2. I want the plot to redraw whenever `T` or `data` changes.

How do I get my widget to respond to changes in my global variable?